# Saving a publishing page content programmatically

Tags: publishing-page, content

On my publishing pages i have a custom user control that contains a SAVE button when the page is in Edit Mode. On click event of that button i do:

```
this.page.Update();
this.page.CheckIn(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " page saved");
this.page.Publish(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " page published");
Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + this.page.Url);
```

But the contents are not being updated? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about trying this code?

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext.Current, false, "Time Saved = " + DateTime.Now);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.savebutton.saveitem.aspx

also have the update at the bottom not top of the code stack, you could try somthing like this ;) :

http://praveenbattula.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/set-page-layout-programatically-for.html

hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks, i will try it when i go back to work tomorrow. but what is wrong with my way of doing save?

Comment: i think the issue is when you do it manually, by that i mean when you do it yourself on the page you check out the page then make the changes, you then save the page and the check in the page. The last step is to publish the page and update :)

Comment: Hello it worked. Actually what to do after SaveButton.SaveItem() ? only page.Publish() ?

Comment: yes, do the checkin, then save then publish